# For a continuous function $f$ exists $g$ whose $n$th derivative equals $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, riemann-integration

I'm trying to solve the next problem: Let $f$ be continuous on $\left[0,a\right]$.
For $x\in\left[0,a\right]$ define $f_{0}\left(x\right)=f\left(x\right)$
and $f_{n+1}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{x}\left(x-t\right)^{n}f\left(t\right)dt$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $n$th derivative of $f_{n}$ exists
and is equal to $f$.

Using the Leibniz's integral rule is easy to see that $f_{n}'=f_{n-1}$
and with this we obtain that $f_{n}^{\left(n\right)}=f$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
But for this rule are used partial derivatives so I think that may
be I can't use that, because we haven't seen this in Riemann integral.
I also tried to do it using integration by parts. Since $f$ is continuous
then $f$ has a primitve $F\left(x\right)=\int_{0}^{x}f\left(t\right)dt$.
Then integrating by parts I obtained that

$$f_{n+1}\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{\left(n-1\right)!}\int_{0}^{x}\left(x-t\right)^{n-1}F\left(t\right)dt.
$$

The last equality seems some related with $f_{n}$ but I don't know
how to differentiate this expression using only fundamental theorem
of calculus or I don't know if there is another way to do the problem.
Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you could expand $(x-t)^n$ by the Binomial theorem, bring $x^k$ outside the integral and then differentiate each term using the product rule.  Seems messy though and not as insight-provoking as the partial differentiation route (or expressing the $n$th antiderivative as a multiple integral and then changing the order of integration using Fubini's theorem).

Comment: The quickest is of course Leibniz's integral rule. But aside from that, another option might be to directly prove that $ \int_0^x f_n(y) \, dy = f_{n+1}(x)$. However, doing this efficiently requires the use of Fubini's theorem to exchange the order of integration, so you might not like this approach either. As a last resort, use binomial theorem as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proceed by induction on $n$.  For the inductive step, applying the inductive hypothesis to your result from integration by parts, we get $f_{n+1}^{(n)}(x) = F(x)$, so $f_{n+1}^{(n+1)}(x) = F'(x) = f(x)$.